# How it is possible to import express from 'express' without a default export?

Tags: typescript, import, commonjs

Using typescript and installing @types/express it is possible to import the express as a default, but there's no export default on express index.d.ts.
I know there's the flag allowSyntheticDefaultImports, but even setting to true i can't replicate the same effect.
How is this possible? I can't find the nomenclature and related questions for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the line:

```
export = e;
```

[This thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7185) and more specifically [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7185#issuecomment-421632656) have nice explanations about how different export/import work